# CV joint broken after brake repair, related?

Tags: brakes, automatic-transmission, brake-rotor, cv-joint, front-wheel-drive

On my front wheel drive vehicle I had all my rear brakes and rotors replaced. The following day my cv joint snapped, less than 10 miles driven.

Could this in anyway be related to the repair? Or just a freak coincidence? I do have a lot of miles on the car.

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

That is, sadly, coincidence.

The rear brake work did not involve touching the front wheels or drive shafts at all. The most that would happen was suspension movement depending on the type of lift or hoist that was used.

Comment: Well it's *possible* the ramp or lift was the cause, but the OP will never be able to prove it. I know someone who had a brand new car (less than 100 miles on the clock) completely scrapped when some klutz doing some customization managed to get it to "fall off the ramp". It hit the ground wheels first, but hard enough to bend the subframe!

Comment: @alephzero I saw someone with a car 6 feet in the air rev the engine and the auto box had a fault which selected drive, shot straight into the parts dept through the wall... Customer was not happy that his 10 minute check was now extended to 4 days... :)  But the difference here was this was dealt with by the garage with no issues, and they lent the customer a car.